# Cannot access external IP of Load Balancer in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubectl, minio, k3s

I created a load balancer service and the describe command returns the following:

```
Name:                     minio-service
Namespace:                minio
Labels:                   app=minio
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=minio
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.150.49
IPs:                      10.43.151.50
LoadBalancer Ingress:     192.168.31.12, 192.168.32.13, 192.168.33.14
Port:                     <unset>  9012/TCP
TargetPort:               9011/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30777/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.10.110:9011,10.42.10.111:9011
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

If I try `curl http://192.168.31.12:9012` it returns:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.31.12 port 9012: Connection
> timed out

Furthermore, I observed something strange.

> kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION        INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION       CONTAINER-RUNTIME
antonis-dell   Ready    control-plane,master   4h42m   v1.21.2+k3s1   192.168.31.12    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS               4.15.0-147-generic   containerd://1.4.4-k3s2
knodea         Ready    <none>                 4h9m    v1.21.2+k3s1   192.168.32.13   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.10.17-v7l+         containerd://1.4.4-k3s2
knodeb         Ready    <none>                 4h2m    v1.21.2+k3s1   192.168.33.14   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.51-v7l+          containerd://1.4.4-k3s2
```

which means that LoadBalancer Ingress ips are the same with internal ips of nodes in the cluster.

Does anyone know why I have three LoadBalancer Ingress ips which are the same as the internal node ips and how to fix this?

Comment: The Load Balancer ingress IPs being the same as the internal IPs of nodes in the cluster is unusual. For further analysis, I would like to have more information on how you created the environment along with the description of the deployment.
Meanwhile, you can try adding annotations to your service configuration. 
Also, refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/ for detailed steps on load balancer service creation.

Comment: do you achieve to any solution ?

Comment: I managed to make it work using port-forward. Options: a) kubectl port-forward minio-0 9000 -n minio -- Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 9000, b) kubectl port-forward --address 192.168.10.70 pod/minio-0 9000 -n minio -- Forwarding from 192.168.10.70:9000 -> 9000, c) kubectl port-forward --address 192.168.10.70 svc/minio-service 9012 -n minio -- Forwarding from 192.168.10.70:9012 -> 9011